# Remote desktop session ends abruptly with a "protocol error"

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp

Intermittently we get a problem where a remote desktop session will get disconnected with the error message “Because of a protocol error, this session will be disconnected. Please try connecting to the remote computer again.”

We are getting this with one server only which is running Windows Server 2008, connecting with Windows 7 clients. The session itself stays running, you just get disconnected, and you can try and reconnect. Sometimes you get in for a while then it will kick you out.

We are connecting from Windows 7 clients. We have tried connecting using Cord on a Mac and this works fine, so it's not like the session itself is corrupted.

One problem is that there are some critical applications running under the session (I know, let's not discuss the idiocy of that), so we cannot reset the session in any way during the working day – so any diagnostics must have minimum impact.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Is this happening with all of your windows 7 client?

Comment: Yes - once the session is in this 'state', I can't connect from any Windows 7 client (I don't have Vista/XP to try). I can connect using Cord from Mac or some other open source product on CentOS.

Answer (score 10):

This problem may occur due to low memory on the remote server.

For me, doing the following fixed the problem:

1. Go to the **Experience** tab, and disable the following:

   - Desktop Composition
   - Visual Styles
   - Persistent bitmap caching
2. Go to the **Display** tab:

   - Set a smaller resolution
   - Lower the **color depth** (for example 15 bit)
3. Also, if you don't need the *remote audio*, go to *Local Resources* tab:

   - Click the **Remote audio -> Settings...**, check **Do not play** and **Do not record**

No need to change the RDP Compression from the Group Policy on the remote machine, only disabling these should do the trick.

Tested to work on **Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1** as the remote, and **Windows 10 Pro** as the client.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and luckily I found the solution on the [social.technet.microsoft.com forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/4523ce86-9a0b-4e6c-90d1-225ddda67ce5):

> ... Change the RDP Compression setting on the server to "Balances memory and network bandwidth" (recommended) or "Optimized to use less memory" using Group Policy.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this the next time it occurs. I've had a paid support case open with Microsoft for months now...jumped through 100 hoops with no resolution. I'll report back the result the next time the error pops up.

Answer (score 4):

This is normally caused by low RAM availability / full system volume or swap-file drive being full on the system you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

A possible test is to see if this occurs with Windows 7 clients connecting through a different IP network/subnet (if the current situation occurs with local network clients).