# Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, google-compute-engine

I tried to connect to my VPS on Google's VPS service, which is Windows 2008 service pack 1 based, and found this error: ''Because of a protocol error, this session will be disconnected. Please try connecting to the remote computer again.''

Comment: Related posts - [Remote desktop session ends abruptly with a "protocol error"](https://serverfault.com/q/200700/329172) & [Remote desktop connection protocol error 0x112f](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31402343/465053)

Answer (score 0):

This is the common error with Windows Server 2008 SP1, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2273487/error-message-when-you-shadow-a-remote-desktop-service-session-in-wind) you can find more information from Microsoft and it's not related to the Google Compute Engine.

When a user remote controls another user's session using Remote Desktop Services Manager or Terminal Services Manager on a Windows Server 2008-based computer, and then stops remote controlling, one or both sessions are disconnected with the mentioned error.

**CAUSE**

This problem occurs if Remote Desktop Connection Client version 6.0.6001 or 6.0.6002 is used with the highest RDP Compression setting. Windows Server 2008 SP1/SP2 defaults to a lower RDP Compression setting, and thus will only exhibit the above symptoms if the setting has been changed to "Optimized to use less network bandwidth", which is the maximum. Windows Server 2008 R2 defaults to the maximum RDP Compression setting.

**WORKAROUND**

Change the RDP Compression setting on the server to "Balances memory and network bandwidth" (recommended) or "Optimized to use less memory" using Group Policy. If using Windows Server 2008 R2 you may also choose "Do not use an RDP compression algorithm".

You can solve this problem following this guideline for Windows Server 2008 (SP1 or SP2) from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4523ce86-9a0b-4e6c-90d1-225ddda67ce5/because-of-a-protocol-error-this-session-will-be-disconnected-please-try-connecting-to-remote?forum=w7itprogeneral):

1. Logon to the Terminal Services computer as an Administrator
2. `Start->Run` `gpedit.msc`, click `Continue` if prompted by UAC
3. In the left pane, under Computer Configuration, navigate to following:

   Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Remote Session Environment
4. In the right pane, double-click on `Set compression algorithm for RDP data`
5. Select `Enabled`, and choose `Balances memory and network bandwidth`
6. Click `OK` to save the change

On the other hand, the cause of that issue could be low amount of available RAM, or limited free space on the system volume or volume with swap-file drive on your VPS you're trying to connect to - check available resources of your VPS and/or decrease quality setting for RDP connection.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community or can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.